# Excel VBA US/UK date conversion issue

Tags: vba, excel, datetime, copy

I am having an issue with a VBA script used to import data from one spreadsheet, reformat it, then transmit it on.

The date entries in the source sheet are entered in dd/mm/yyyy format. The destination sheet uses the following line to import the date:

```
If RolandSource.Worksheets(tFocus).Cells(rFocus, 2).Value <> "" And RolandSource.Worksheets(tFocus).Cells(4, cFocus) <> "" And RolandSource.Worksheets(tFocus).Cells(rFocus, cFocus) <> "" Then ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(rRecord, 6).Value = RolandSource.Worksheets(tFocus).Cells(rFocus, cFocus).Value
```

The issue is that excel is copying the data, then automatically formatting as a date. During this process, dates that are ambiguous between UK and US date formats are being transformed, despite this not being needed.

The dataset that is being imported may contain date (dd/mm/yyyy) or text entries, and as such usual date processing routes create errors. Does anybody have suggestions?

You can see the issue I am describing by formatting cell A1 as Text, typing "01/02/2003" into Cell A1, then executing the following in the immediate window:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(1,2).value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(1,1).Value
```

(Please note, the solution will be used as part of a loop that needs to handle dates and words).

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Execute `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(1,2).NumberFormat = "@"` first, after that execute `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(1,2).Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(1,1).Value` to prevent autoformatting in target cell.

Comment: Excel stores dates as serial numbers with `1 Jan 1900` = `1`.  If you enter something that looks like a date, Excel will parse it in accord with the Windows Regional Short Date settings.  If the dates in the `RolandSource` are "real dates", the solution will be different than if they are text representations of dates.   If they are text representations, then pre-format your column as text, and then copy the `.Text` property of source cell.  If they are real dates, and correct, you shouldn't be having this problem, but you could try accessing the `.Value2` property of the source cell.

Comment: Thanks @omegastripes, tried this solution but causes the loop to fail.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - The issue is the field in the source is formatted as text and contains non-date text values (IE: "DNA") and dates in UK format (IE:"15/04/2003"). The script lifts these values from the source to the destination, but where dates are acceptable in UK and US format (IE: "01/02/2003") excel assumes they are incorrect US format and converting to UK format (storing 02/01/2003 as a date value). Value2 does not resolve either; if I do the following:
    MsgBox(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(1,1).Value2)
from the above the behaviour is correct, but using the line above it fails.

Comment: What happens if you format the column as text before you write the values into it?

Comment: Hi @RonRosenfeld, this resolves the issue, as did omegastripes solution, however broke the loop. Marking as answered though, as I then managed to ad some IF() statements in to protect against failure. Not an eloquent solution, but worked. (PS: how can I +1 you both for your support on this?)

Comment: Through trial and error, I have come across another change that seems to work, although I don't understand why.  Try removing the `.Value`  property .  In 2016, with both columns formatted as General, it seems to work. IOW,`Cell1 = Cell2`, where `Cell2` contains text date, leaves it as text date.  Whereas `Cell1.Value = Cell2.Value` tries to change it into a real date, sometimes incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @OmegaStripes and @RonRosenfeld - answer was to format the cell prior to copying the value from source to destination. This was causing the loop to fail, but by adding If() statements to protect the loop from error I have resolved. Thank you both for your help.